# how to alert the user on duplications in the moving file procces in a Web-Application

Tags: c#, exception, server-side

I have a source and destination path with the same folder and file names (source has some extra files). my question is when I have cut source locations files and folders and to paste the destination location

1. how to copied initially the extra files(destination not having files)?
2. how to through the error after paste the extra files "the folder and files already exist do you want to replace it" message?
3. after getting the response how can I move and delete the source files?

somebody can help me guys I am stuck with this logic nearly 2 days.

Note: am the beginner of the C# server side code.

thanks, advance. Hi All, thank you for your reply, I have written the same structure with #RezaNoei mentioned my code was

```
private void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool replace, string action)
    {
        try
        {
            // Gets the subdirectories for the specified directory.
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

            var dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
            // If the destination directory doesn't exist, creates it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }

            // Gets the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
            var files = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var oldPath = Path.Combine(sourceDirName, file.Name);
                var temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
                var fileExist = File.Exists(temppath);
                if (!fileExist)
                {
                    if (action != "paste")
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File.Move(oldPath, temppath);
                    }
                }
                else if (fileExist && replace)
                {
                    File.Delete(temppath);
                    if (action != "paste")
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        File.Move(oldPath, temppath);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (action == "paste")
            {
                DeleteDirectory(sourceDirName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code, that makes it a lot easier to find errors and answer.

Comment: Surely after 2 days you must have *some* code written? Please share so we can help you. Off the top of my head, I would think something like this might work: `foreach (var sourceFilePath in sourceFilePaths)
{
    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath)))
    {
        // show file exists message and get response;
        if (response == "no") continue;
    }

    File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destinationDirectory, true);
}`

Comment: Hi All, thank you for your reply, I have written the same structure with #RezaNoei mentioned my code was

Answer (score 0):

Use this Function:

**Note:** If you are developing a web-application and you want to alert this through Html, it doesn't help you. Please read the Next Section **"For Web-Application"**
**Note2:** this function doesn't check for inner folders. so if you have a nested path, we should write a recursive function.

```
    public void Copy(string Source, string Destination)
    {
        string[] SourceFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Source);
        for (int i = 0; i < SourceFiles.Length; i++)
        {
            string DestinationFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Destination, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(SourceFiles[i]));
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(DestinationFilePath))
            {
                var DialogResult = MessageBox.Show($"File `{System.IO.Path.GetFileName(SourceFiles[i])}` Exists in the Destination. Are you want to overwrite this file ?", "File Exist !", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    System.IO.File.Copy(SourceFiles[i], DestinationFilePath, true);
            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(SourceFiles[i], DestinationFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

**For Web-Application:**

You actually need to interact with User. And it make our work more complicated than before.

You will Work with Session and you must keep track of this Operation. I don't know which technology are you using but you must but added these ones to Session:

```
 1-1 **Destination Folder**
 1-2 **List of Duplicated SourceFiles**
```

So:

1. Next Step is to copy non-duplicated files and Added Duplication on Session:

   ```
   public void Copy(string Source, string Destination)
   {
       /// Set Session ....
       Session["Destination"] = Destination;

       List<string> DuplicatedFiles = new List<string>();

       string[] SourceFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Source);
       for (int i = 0; i < SourceFiles.Length; i++)
       {
           string DestinationFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Destination, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(SourceFiles[i]));

           if (System.IO.File.Exists(DestinationFilePath))
           {
              // Add into Duplication List
              DuplicatedFiles.Add(SourceFiles[i]);
           }
           else
           {
               System.IO.File.Copy(SourceFiles[i], DestinationFilePath);
           }
       }
       /// Set Session .....
       Session["DouplicatedFiles"] = DuplicatedFiles;
   }
   ```

above code is psudo and the goal is Clear.

2. Next Step is to show the result of copying or duplications:

I don'n know how do you want to implement such a view for duplication errors and it will not the part of the answer. anyway you may want to let the user to choose the action on **each** files separately or **whole** of them at the same time.

depend on your preferences you will have an ActionMethod (In MVC) or something else in WebForm that will do these things: 
(If user doesn't want replace the files, it's easy to forget the action)

```
 public void CopyDuplications(bool Overwrite)
 {
    if (!Overwrite)
      return "OK";
    else 
    {
        string Destination = Session["Destination"] as string;
        var DuplicatedFiles = Session["DouplicatedFiles"] as List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i< DuplicatedFiles.Count; i++) 
        {
            string DestinationFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Destination, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(DuplicatedFiles[i]));

            System.IO.File.Copy(DuplicatedFiles[i], DestinationFilePath, true);
        }
    }  
 }
```

Comment: thanks, but my case is which one your first statement "If you are developing a web-application and you want to alert this through Html, it doesn't help you." I need to do this case

Comment: Hi @RezaNoei, thanks, I think this code works only in MVC. If this was workable in Core means than please tell me what are the namespaces and NuGet packages are need to be installed and referred. to use this function.